# Using Swift protocol delegation on a struct to change values?

Tags: swift, struct, delegates, swift-protocols

I have a project where I want there are `factories` with `orders` (an array of `Ints`) that can be mutated.

I want all the code mutating, adding, removing, validating, etc of orders in another class (ie: almost like a proxy pattern) and when ready update the factory with the new orders.

I follow a delegate pattern to kick the new orders back to the factory for updating, however the factory orders never update.

**Note: I know this is because the factory is a `struct` and that it is a value type**

I am wondering if its possible to update the struct using a delegate pattern; or must I change it to a reference type (a class) in order to resolve the issue.

In the following code I've stripped out all the validation, push, pop and other features and am keeping it simple for this query by force changing the order array and then using a delegate to kick back the changed orders.

```
// Swift playground code

protocol OrderUpdatedDelegate {
    mutating func ordersDidUpdate(_ orders: [Int])
}

//  This class will handle all the validation to do with 
// orders array, but for now; lets just force 
// change the orders to test the delegate pattern
class OrderBook {
    var delegate: OrderUpdatedDelegate?
    var orders: [Int] = [Int]()

    init(orders: [Int]) {
        self.orders = orders
    }

    func changeOrders() {
        self.orders = [7,8,1]
        print ("updated orders to -> \(orders)")
        delegate?.ordersDidUpdate(orders)
    }
}

struct Factory {
    var orders: [Int] = [Int]()

    init(orders: [Int]) {
        self.orders = orders
    }
}

extension Factory: OrderUpdatedDelegate {
    mutating func ordersDidUpdate(_ orders: [Int]) {
        print ("recieved: \(orders)")
        self.orders = orders
    }
}

var shop = Factory(orders: [1,2,3])
let book = OrderBook.init(orders: shop.orders)
book.changeOrders()

print ("\nBook.orders = \(book.orders)")
print ("Shop.orders = \(shop.orders)")
```

Output:

> Book.orders = [7, 8, 1]
>
> Shop.orders = [1, 2, 3]

Again, I know the reason is because I've declared factory to be a `struct`; but I'm wondering if its possible to use a delegate pattern to mutate the orders array within the struct?

If not, I'll change it to a class; but I appreciate any feedback on this.

With thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code, both of which needs fixing for it to work:

- using a value type
- not setting the delegate

Once you set the delegate, you'll see `ordersDidUpdate` actually getting called, but `shop.orders` will still have its original value. That is because as soon as you mutate your `Factory`, the `delegate` set on `OrderBook` will be a different object from the mutated `Factory`, which was updated in the delegate call `ordersDidUpdate`.

Using a reference type fixes this issue.

Couple of things to keep in mind when you switch to a `class` delegate. Make your `OrderUpdatedDelegate` be a class-bound protocol, then remove `mutating` from the function declaration. And most importantly, always declare class-bound delegates as `weak` to avoid strong reference cycles.

```
protocol OrderUpdatedDelegate: class {
    func ordersDidUpdate(_ orders: [Int])
}

//  This class will handle all the validation to do with
// orders array, but for now; lets just force
// change the orders to test the delegate pattern
class OrderBook {
    weak var delegate: OrderUpdatedDelegate?
    var orders: [Int] = []

    init(orders: [Int]) {
        self.orders = orders
    }

    func changeOrders() {
        self.orders = [7,8,1]
        print ("updated orders to -> \(orders)")
        delegate?.ordersDidUpdate(orders)
    }
}

class Factory {
    var orders: [Int] = []

    init(orders: [Int]) {
        self.orders = orders
    }
}

extension Factory: OrderUpdatedDelegate {
    func ordersDidUpdate(_ orders: [Int]) {
        print("receieved: \(orders)")
        self.orders = orders
        print("updated order: \(self.orders)")
    }
}

var shop = Factory(orders: [1,2,3])
let book = OrderBook(orders: shop.orders)
book.delegate = shop
book.changeOrders()

print ("Book.orders = \(book.orders)")
print ("Shop.orders = \(shop.orders)")
```

Comment: yes, i forgot to add the delegate.   That was my fault.   Again, I think you are right; if I want reference changes, use references not structs

Answer (score 1):

As you said since `Factory` is a struct, when setting `OrderBook` `delegate` its already copied there so the `delegate` is actually a copy of your original factory instance.

A `class` is the appropriate solution for this.

Comment: Agreed.  I think I just confused myself when I was coding.  The actual program has a factory that is a class.   I think I was having trouble getting the delegate pattern to work but still abstract the factory from the orderbook class